# Signing up for an Apple Developer Account under 18

Tags: developer-program

I am looking to launch an app within the next few days on the store. I have done this before in the past under a parents name but as I am 17 and will be 18 in a few months wandered whether it would be worth signing up to the program with my own account now.

I have read other posts on the min. age being 18 but is there anything that could feasibly happen as a result of this? Or am I just better off doing it under my parent for another year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Launch the app through your parent's name, you are still under 18 and this will ensure your legal obligations are met.

When you turn 18, you can create a new Apple Developer account in your name and [transfer your apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html) from your parent's account to your new account.

I believe the transfer will include your statistics and other meta-data associated with each app.

This approach is common practice for consultants who develop and manage apps for clients, before handing them over when their role ends.

With regard to choosing the bank account, so long as your parents agree this should be fine.

Comment: Ok thanks. When I turn 18 would my stats etc. Transfer over? Also am I right in thinking that I could setup the account in parent name but set my bank to be the one where sales revenue would go into?

Comment: I have extended my answer. Yes, transfer apps over to your new account. Yes, I believe you can set the bank account to any that your parents agree to. Great to be publishing apps at this stage of your life; good luck!

Comment: Thanks man - much appreciated. Hope to be publishing some bigger and better apps in the future :)